# Get the value based on row before

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table

```
+-----+-----+
| A   | B   |
+-----+-----+
|  1  | 300 |
|  2  | 300 |
|  3  | 0   |
|  4  | 0   |
|  5  | 100 |
|  6  | 100 |
|  7  | 100 |
|  8  | 100 |
|  9  | 0   |
| 10  | 0   |
+-----+-----+
```

Given a value let's say 100, I need to get the first row of this value where the row before is equal to 0 (in the order of increasing A).

The output would be :

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
|  5  | 100 |
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database table is an unordered set of rows. When you say "first row" and "row before", I assume that you mean in the order of increasing `A`

You can use user variable to do this:

```
set @val := 100;   -- to be searched
set @pre := -999999999;

select a, b
from (
select
    t.*,
    if(
        @val = b and @pre = 0,   -- if the required value is found and last value was 0
        if(@pre := b, 1, 1),     -- then 1
        if(@pre := b, 0, 0)      -- else 0
    ) flag
from t
order by A
) t where flag = 1;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/TZUH17346)

Comment: I choose this as the perfect solution because it handles repetitions of B value

Comment: Is there a chance to get the php version of this?

Answer (score 1):

How about an `INNER JOIN` on itself.

**Input**

```
// From the demo provided in comments.

+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
|   1 | 300 |
|   2 | 300 |
|   3 |   0 |
|   4 |   0 |
|   5 | 100 |
|   6 | 100 |
|   7 | 100 |
|   8 | 100 |
|   9 |   0 |
|  10 |   0 |
|  11 |   0 |
|  12 |   0 |
|  13 | 100 |
|  14 | 100 |
|  15 | 100 |
|  16 |   0 |
|  17 |   0 |
|  18 |   0 |
|  19 |   0 |
|  20 | 100 |
|  20 | 100 |
|  20 | 100 |
|  21 | 100 |
|  24 |   0 |
+-----+-----+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT yt1.A, MIN(yt1.B) AS B
FROM YourTable yt1
INNER JOIN YourTable yt2 ON yt2.A = yt1.A - 1
WHERE yt1.B = 100 AND yt2.B = 0
GROUP BY yt1.A
```

**Output**

```
// As requested in the demo.

+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
|   5 | 100 |
|  13 | 100 |
|  20 | 100 |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Can you work this out to handle repetitions of B value like in this [demo](http://rextester.com/KFV4204)

Comment: Because even if **GROUP BY** is removed it only gets one sequence!

Comment: This gets all the values, please take a look at the demo!

Comment: I see, maybe the reason is because A is not unique and could be repeated too?!

Comment: @0x58 See updated answer, and also this [demo](http://rextester.com/live/PRRHHL9653).